# Can I use switch user "su" with keys / certificate?

Tags: ssh, certificate, ssh-keys

I just locked myself out of SSH.  Basically, I added three users to /etc/ssh/sshd_config using the AllowUsers directive, which is great because now they can login, but now I can't, and I'm the only user on the sudoers list.

I would happily do an "su" from within an SSH session of one of those users I just added, but I do not have the password for my account, only a .pem certificate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, won't work. Best bet: reboot your (remote?) machine into recovery mode if this is possible and modify the configuration then. And an advice for the future: keep an existing shell open and try to re-login with your existing account in a new session before terminating (no offense meant).

Comment: I've learned the same lesson except for me it was a bad sudoers file :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I guess it's just one of those learning experiences.  What surprises me nonetheless is that I cannot switch users with a certificate...

Comment: Your server-stored certificate probably lives in $HOME/.ssh which is a directory that "belongs" to OpenSSH. You could dive into the world of PAM modules (look at /etc/pam.d/) in order to change the configuration of sudo. There are plenty of PAM modules out there, for example you could use a smartcard reader that way.